# How do I turn a string of digits into a list of one-digit integers?

Tags: python, numbers, digit

```
str(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(1, 11))) -> this returns 10! or '3628800'
```

Without creating a `for` loop, how can I map this function to another function as a list of one-digit integers: e.g. `reduce(lambda x, y: x+ y, [3, 6, 2, 8, 8, 0, 0])`

Clarification:

`reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [str(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(1, 11)))])`

How do I turn everything inside the `[ ]` into a list of one-digit integers so that the first function can evaluate it? Of course I need to transform it **inside** the `[ ]`.

Comment: Not quite getting what specific outcome you're asking for, unfortunately.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you're asking how to convert a number into a list of its (base 10) digits, without using a loop? You may want to reformulate the question, since it's not very clear

Comment: "Without creating a `for` loop" is a weird condition to specify. Is this homework?

Comment: Consider using `math.factorial` (if available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[int(x) for x in str(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(1, 11)))]
```

The final product:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [int(x) for x in str(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(1, 11)))])
```

Comment: There you go! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're simply looking for `map(int, s)` where `s` is the string you want to get integer digits from.  For example:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.factorial(10)
3628800
>>> str(math.factorial(10))
'3628800'
>>> map(int,str(math.factorial(10)))
[3, 6, 2, 8, 8, 0, 0]
>>> sum(map(int,str(math.factorial(10))))
27
```